# Why is boolean toggling to "true" but not back to false?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

In my listView adapter class I have a delegate to assign a function to each button in my listview. This button should toggle a boolean called `cupboard` inside my "Spices" object. It works upon the first click and changes it to "true". But it won't go back to false again. Any idea what is causing it to not set back to false again? This is my first post here so apologies if it's a duplicate.

I've tried changing the default value of "false" to having a getter and setter and tried different if/else statements to toggle the bool values as well.

This is from the custom listView adapter inside the `GetView()` function:

```
Button AddToCupboard = row.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.AddToCupboard);
//Adds onclick event for "Add to cupboard"

AddToCupboard.Click += delegate
{
    var item = mItems[position].cupboard;
     item = !item;
    Console.WriteLine(item);
};
```

My `Spice` class:

```
class Spice
{
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string flavour { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string substitute { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string uses { get; set; }


    public bool cupboard { get; set; }
    public bool list { get; set; }
}
```

I expected console to output `True` then `False` when the same button is pressed twice, but it just stays at `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you are not actually changing the `cupboard` value from the Spice object.

```
AddToCupboard.Click += delegate
{
    var mItem = mItems[position];
    mItem.cupboard = !mItem.cupboard;
}
```

In your example, you would copy the `cupboard` value into a local variable, toggled it from T to F and that was all. The `mItems` array would stay unmodified because all the operations were done on a copy of the interested variable.

Comment: Thank you! worked like a charm. Can you explain why declaring "mItems[position].cupboard" doesn't change the cupboard value? Im quite new and want to learn from mistakes.

Comment: So I was changing the value of "item" not the value of "cupboard"?

Comment: Yes. I was just writing a longer response. You copied the value of cupboard into another variable that is no more linked to the mItems[position].cupboard. That means if you change the value of the item, it does not automatically change the value of the mItems[position].cupboard.

Comment: In my example, from your mItems array, I got a reference to one of the object and I am changing a property of the object. This is where things are different. An object is a reference type while an integer/boolean/decimal is a value type. I recommend you to read about Value Types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) and Reference Types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).